# js the code stops working after navigating the routes without rebooting the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have js code that is responsible for the select. The site works without reloading the pages (use `nuxt`). The problem is that if I switch over routes, then this select does not work. How can I fix this?

```
$(function () {
        $('.select_list_radio').on('click', function(){
            var current = $(this).find('label span').text();
            $(this).parents('.select_list_wrapper').find('.select_list_current .select_list_current_item').text(current);
            $(this).parents('.select_list_wrapper').removeClass('open');
            $(this).parents('.select_list_wrapper').find('.select_list').css('display', 'block');
        });
    })
```

Comment: Are you calling this when the `.select_list_radio` element is not present in the DOM?

Comment: @thanksd

No, the first time the page loads, the select works. Then, when I go on routes it stops working. If you reload the page, it will again start working

Answer (score 0):

You must never make a change to an element Vuejs manages because Vue won’t be aware of the change and is going to go right ahead and overwrite it in the next update cycle.

So you can try to wrapper your `.select_list_radio` to a new component, or better, try to think in Vue and just put jQuery away.

You can read how to safely use jQuery with Vuejs in this link: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/